# Bibliographic database for books

Tags: api, database, books

Im developing an application where I need to display some bibliographic information of books (title, author, publisher, description and book cover).

In order to do so im looking for API's to get this data.

I read about the following API's:

1. Google books
2. Goodreads
3. LibraryThing
4. OpenLibrary

but each has it's limitations such as 1 call per second/ 50,000 calls a day and so on, so im looking for more databases with hope to find a good data with less restrictive limitations.

Any recommendations will be appreciated.